# VS Code and node modules

Tags: visual-studio-code

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVwH3VL1EsA&feature=emb_title) and I tried installing everything to start learning to use translation between HTML pages.

Following the video, I installed VS Code and git bash. I then put in the command lines he talks about and it seems to work just fine, but I can't find the way to access the node modules afterwards. They don't show up in the side panel like in the video.

The guy has a section "current project" that I don't have either.

Comment: Did you actually open the right directory in VS Code? Try e.g. `code .` to open the current working directory in the IDE.

Comment: oh.. wow... I just got bamboozled. I have no idea what I just did, but it worked. I typed code . and a new window poped up and node modules was there. Thank you so much:!!! now, I just need to figure out WHY it worked. cheers!!

Comment: I don't think you mean `translation`